# Key length error of AES input in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, encryption, aes, sha

I am trying to implement AES in matlab by using the matlab files from this website: http://buchholz.hs-bremen.de/aes/aes.htm

I put my secret key in a hash function (SHA-256) and I have a key in 64 char format:

```
CD00E292C5970D3C5E2F0FFA5171E555BC46BFC4FADDFB4A418B6840B86E79A3
```

Whenever I want to feed the AES function with this input, it gives me this error:

> Error using cipher function
>   w has to be an array (not a cell array) with [44 x 4] elements.

I think my input's format is wrong, but I am confused. Can anyone help me to solve the error above? Thank you in advance.

```
function ciphertext = cipher (plaintext, w, s_box, poly_mat, vargin)
%CIPHER  Convert 16 bytes of plaintext to 16 bytes of ciphertext.
%   CIPHERTEXT = CIPHER (PLAINTEXT, W, S_BOX, POLY_MAT) 
%   converts PLAINTEXT to CIPHERTEXT,
%   using the expanded cipher key W, 
%   the byte substitution table S_BOX, and
%   the transformation matrix POLY_MAT.
%   CIPHERTEXT = CIPHER (PLAINTEXT, W, S_BOX, POLY_MAT, 1) 
%   switches verbose mode on, which displays intermediate results.
%   PLAINTEXT has to be a vector of 16 bytes (0 <= PLAINTEXT(i) <= 255).
%   W has to be a [44 x 4]-matrix of bytes (0 <= W(i,j) <= 255).

% If there is an optional "verbose mode" argument
if nargin > 4

% Switch the verbose mode flag on
verbose_mode = 1;

% If there is no optional "verbose mode" argument
else

% Switch the verbose mode flag off
verbose_mode = 0;

end

% If the input vector is a cell array or does not have 16 elements
if iscell (plaintext) | prod (size (plaintext)) ~= 16

% Inform user and abort
error ('Plaintext has to be a vector (not a cell array) with 16 elements.')

end

% If any element of the input vector cannot be represented by 8 bits
if any (plaintext < 0 | plaintext > 255)

% Inform user and abort
error ('Elements of plaintext vector have to be bytes (0 <= plaintext(i) <=    255).')

end

% If the expanded key array is a cell arrray or does not have the correct size
if iscell (w) | any (size (w) ~= [44, 4])

% Inform user and abort
error ('w has to be an array (not a cell array) with [44 x 4] elements.')

end

% If any element of the expanded key array can not be represented by 8 bits
if any (w < 0 | w > 255)

% Inform user and abort
error ('Elements of key array w have to be bytes (0 <= w(i,j) <= 255).')

end

% Display headline if requested
if verbose_mode
disp (' ')
disp ('********************************************')
disp ('*                                          *')
disp ('*               C I P H E R                *')
disp ('*                                          *')
disp ('********************************************')
disp (' ')
end

% Copy the 16 elements of the input vector 
% column-wise into the 4 x 4 state matrix
state = reshape (plaintext, 4, 4);

% Display intermediate result if requested
if verbose_mode
disp_hex ('Initial state :                  ', state)
end

% Copy the first 4 rows (4 x 4 elements) of the expanded key 
% into the current round key.
% Transpose to make this column-wise
round_key = (w(1:4, :))';

% Display intermediate result if requested
if verbose_mode
    disp_hex ('Initial round key :              ', round_key)
end

% Add (xor) the current round key (matrix) to the state (matrix)
state = add_round_key (state, round_key);

% Loop over 9 rounds
for i_round = 1 : 9

% Display intermediate result if requested
    if verbose_mode
        disp_hex (['State at start of round ', num2str(i_round),' :      '],   state)
    end

% Substitute all 16 elements of the state matrix
% by shoving them through the S-box
    state = sub_bytes (state, s_box);

% Display intermediate result if requested
    if verbose_mode
        disp_hex ('After sub_bytes :                ', state)
    end

% Cyclically shift the last three rows of the state matrix
    state = shift_rows (state);

% Display intermediate result if requested
    if verbose_mode
        disp_hex ('After shift_rows :               ', state)
    end

% Transform the columns of the state matrix via a four-term polynomial
    state = mix_columns (state, poly_mat);

% Display intermediate result if requested
    if verbose_mode
        disp_hex ('After mix_columns :              ', state)
    end

% Extract the current round key (4 x 4 matrix) from the expanded key
    round_key = (w((1:4) + 4*i_round, :))';

% Display intermediate result if requested
    if verbose_mode
        disp_hex ('Round key :                      ', round_key)
    end

% Add (XOR) the current round key (matrix) to the state (matrix)
    state = add_round_key (state, round_key);

end

% Display intermediate result if requested
if verbose_mode
disp_hex ('State at start of final round :  ', state)
end

% Substitute all 16 elements of the state matrix
% by shoving them through the S-box
state = sub_bytes (state, s_box);

% Display intermediate result if requested
if verbose_mode
disp_hex ('After sub_bytes :                ', state)
end

% Cyclically shift the last three rows of the state matrix
state = shift_rows (state);

% Display intermediate result if requested
if verbose_mode
    disp_hex ('After shift_rows :               ', state)
end

% Extract the last round key (4 x 4 matrix) from the expanded key
round_key = (w(41:44, :))';

% Display intermediate result if requested
if verbose_mode
    disp_hex ('Round key :                      ', round_key)
end

% Add (xor) the current round key (matrix) to the state (matrix)
state = add_round_key (state, round_key);

% Display intermediate result if requested
if verbose_mode
    disp_hex ('Final state :                    ', state)
end

% reshape the 4 x 4 state matrix into a 16 element row vector
ciphertext = reshape (state, 1, 16);
```

Comment: Without showing us your implementation of that function and how you're calling it, there is little hope of us knowing why your input is invalid. I would try and follow the advice of the error message and not pass in a cell (again, we have no way of actually seeing the variable type you're passing in)

Comment: function ciphertext=cipher (plaintext, w, s_box, poly_mat, vargin)
%CIPHER Convert 16 bytes of plaintext to 16 bytes of ciphertext.
%CIPHERTEXT=CIPHER(PLAINTEXT, W, S_BOX, POLY_MAT) 
converts PLAINTEXT to CIPHERTEXT,using the expanded cipher key W, the byte substitution table S_BOX,and the transformation matrix POLY_MAT.
%CIPHERTEXT=CIPHER (PLAINTEXT, W, S_BOX, POLY_MAT, 1) switches verbose mode on, which displays intermediate results.
%PLAINTEXT has to be a vector of 16 bytes(0<= PLAINTEXT(i)<=255).
%W has to be [44x4]-matrix of bytes(0<=W(i,j)<=255).

Comment: Hope you find functions' comments helpful to answer my question. Function itself is very very long.Thank you @Wolfie

Comment: Don't post code in comments, click the **edit** button under you question and add it there, indenting by 4 spaces will format it nicely as code

Answer (score 0):

This implementation does only do the encryption of AES. It assumes you will implement the [key schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule) yourself.

Executing the key schedule will give you 11 keys of 16 bytes each. In this implementation this is represented as an array of `[44 x 4]` numbers from 0 to 256. You should pass this array to the `cipher` function.

> Note: When you are implementing this yourself, it is a good idea to familiarize yourself with the [AES block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Description_of_the_cipher) *first*. Understand what the `cipher` function does before implementing parts, because otherwise you will surely get stuck.